# Writing into a div within a view for angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Using Angular JS and document.getElementById('comments1').innerHTML= how do I write into a Div within a view.  I am very new to angular JS and do not know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really 'write into a view' using Angular. More correctly, you set up a property on your scope then bind your view to that property. Something like this.

```
//In your controller
$scope.name = "Tyler';

//In your view
<div> {{name}} </div>
```

Obviously there is a lot more to it though. I'd recommend getting a deeper understanding of the strengths and weaknesses of angular before you decide to use it though.

*If you did actually want to write into a view, you're better off setting up a directive because you shouldn't be doing DOM manipulation anywhere but a directive.